# Calling an API: Place Id is different than expected (Python)

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps-api-3

I am calling an API to access the place id information of a location.  The code is returning the JSON data with the geographical information and place ids, but the place id I am getting does not match the one I am being asked to find.  The first seven characters in the place id are:  "ChIJ18Y."  Could someone please give me some insight on place ids?  Is there a problem with my encoding statement?  Thank you in advance for your inputs!

**Here is what I have done so far:**

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?sensor=false&address=Madras+University'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        continue

    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print location
```

Comment: Is the webservice you're connecting in to using the Google Places API inside or a whole different implementation?

Comment: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson (This is the API endpoint, which is a static subset of Google API data.)

Comment: Update:  So I am getting the correct place id from the Google site when I search for the exact address and not the university name.  My code is giving the right address to the school, but it is not giving the same place id as Google.

Comment: Upd.ate2:  I tried running the program and entering the exact address of the school, and it gave the correct place id, matching Google's

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner. I'm assuming the API endpoint is using the Places API inside as you said. The [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) will give the response with the placeId of the predicted query. From there, we can get the [Place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) with its exact lat/long coordinates as well. Other APIs can be used to get the [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) which has the `formatted_address`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi.~  I sensed and figured that out a few hours ago.  Sorry that I forgot to post an update.  I ended up getting the correct place id after rerunning.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Neat! Please do share to the community the resolution for others who may have the same issue.

Comment: So what was the final solution to get place id?